# C open second connection on socket

Tags: c, sockets

I need to program a distributed hash table with P2P. The peer which gets the request from the client needs to have an open connection to send the response back and also needs to open a connection to its predecessor to receive the information. I tried using accept a second time on the same socket but it didn't work.

I read a few solutions about forking but I'm not sure if it's suitable for my needs. (And I'm not really sure how to implement it correctly here)

My basic setup:

```
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

  if ((gai_status = getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &hints, &md_srvinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", gai_strerror(gai_status));
    exit(gai_status);
  }

  int md_listen_socket = socket(md_srvinfo->ai_family, md_srvinfo->ai_socktype, md_srvinfo->ai_protocol);
  int yes;
  setsockopt(md_listen_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(1));
  bind(md_listen_socket, md_srvinfo->ai_addr, md_srvinfo->ai_addrlen);
  listen(md_listen_socket, 2);

while(1) {

    // accept connection
    struct sockaddr_storage client_address;
    socklen_t addr_size = sizeof(client_address);

    int md_active_socket;
    md_active_socket = accept(md_listen_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, &addr_size);
.
.
.
.
    recv(stuff from predecessor peer)
    send(stuff to md_active_socket)
}
```

Edit:

```
struct addrinfo *pred_srvinfo;
getaddrinfo(NULL, pred_port, &hints, &pred_srvinfo);
int pred_listen_socket = socket(pred_srvinfo->ai_family, pred_srvinfo->ai_socktype, pred_srvinfo->ai_protocol);

struct sockaddr_storage pred_address;
socklen_t pred_addr_size = sizeof(pred_address);
int pred_active_socket = accept(pred_listen_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &pred_address, &pred_addr_size);
connect(pred_active_socket, pred_srvinfo->ai_addr, pred_srvinfo->ai_addrlen);
```

Can someone lead me to the right path?

Comment: The program is acting as both a server (to the peer) and a client (of the predecessor). You have the connection to the peer already (result of `accept(2)`), just open another socket to the predecessor with `socket/connect`. Then talk to each however you need. You do not need to fork, unless this program is expected to handle multiple concurrent requests from the peer and predecessor.

Comment: The code above is the peer, I need to open a second connection to the predecessor peer while keeping the connection to the client open.

Comment: Right, that's the second part of my comment. Make a new socket with `socket(2)`, and `connect(2)` it to the predecessor.

Comment: Why do I need to connect it additionally? Until now listen(), accept() and recv() was enough.

Comment: OK, it seems like you don't quite understand the differences between a server and client. I'd really recommend that you read some basics on the TCP protocol. Or read the man pages, starting with `man 2 socket`. In short, `accept(2)` is for servers (it *accepts* a connection from a client) and `connect(2)` is for clients (it *connects* to a server).

Comment: The [Linux socket overview](https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) is also a good place to start, even if you're not on Linux.

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't use an evented network library, such as libev or facil.io? They should both support client mode as well as sever mode and I think both of them include a solution to the forking concern as well as multi-threading (I'm the author for facil.io, so I may be biased)...?

Comment: Alright I'll start reading, thanks for the help!